# Control which monitor a window opens on

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

How can I control which monitor a window opens on in Windows 10? Windows seems quite random this way. Some windows open on whichever monitor they last were on (a reasonable option), while others (most annoyingly Adobe Reader) always open on the primary monitor instead of the monitor I want them on. Of course I can hit Shift+Win+Left or Right to move the window, but I'd prefer to not have to do that. If there was some program that could just be configured to always place windows from configured applications on a specific monitor, that would be awesome.

There are other related questions, but a) they're really old, mostly predating Windows 10, and b) they end up recommending changing to an entirely new window manager, which seems rather drastic to solve one issue.

For background, I'm a longtime Linux user, and in Ubuntu when I open a window it opens on whichever monitor has the mouse pointer. This is convenient as it gives me a simple way to influence the choice.